# Error - cannot install Miniconda with RStudio

Tags: python, r, installation, miniconda, reticulate

I have written a R script where I use some python lines through the `reticulate` package.
I need to share it with some colleagues who don't know about programming and I've created a batch file so I can run it without them even opening R.

However, I tried using the `install_miniconda()` function to silently install python to run the code without them knowing (I guess people are reluctant to installing a couple of programs) but R throws an error:

```
> reticulate::install_miniconda(path="C:/")
# * Installing Miniconda -- please wait a moment ...
# * Downloading "https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe" ...
# trying URL 'https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe'
# Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 74687656 bytes (71.2 MB)
# downloaded 71.2 MB

# Error: Miniconda installation failed [unknown reason]
```

I tried without passing any path but my computer user has spaces on it so I cannot use it, that's why I resorted to supplying it with the root path "`C:/`"

Can someone help me understand what is happening?

**Note:** I am using R 4.2.1 on Windows 11 (also tried on Windows 10 with the same result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing `rminiconda` from the [`github`](https://github.com/hafen/rminiconda) like this:

```
remotes::install_github("hafen/rminiconda")
rminiconda::install_miniconda(name='your_name')
```

After that you can specify the installation using `reticulate` like this:

```
py <- rminiconda::find_miniconda_python("your_name")
reticulate::use_python(py, required = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't really understand what ois happening here or why is R throwing an error but this successfully installed miniconda and runs perfectly! You just saved my life :)